# Non duplicate serial algorithm

Tags: php

```
<?php

function gen() {
    $hashKey = array_merge(
        range('a', 'z'),
        range(0 ,9)
    );
    $hash = array();

    while (count($hash) < 12) {
        $hash[] = $hashKey[array_rand($hashKey, 1)];
    }

    return implode('', $hash);
}

$hashes = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $hash = gen();

    while (in_array($hash, $hashes) === true) {
        var_dump($i . ' repeated');
        $hash = gen();
    }

    $hashes[] = $hash;
}

var_dump(count($hashes));
var_dump(count(array_unique($hashes)));
```

I need to generate 40000000 serial number, I random and combine `a-z` `0-9` to mix the serial number, it should be `36!` results, but always stuck in 1770, how come?

Comment: Can you explain 'always stuck in 1770'?

Comment: A comment in the `array_rand` doc states that you should shuffle the array and taking the nth first elements before using the function. Did you try that?

Comment: I used this function gen() {
    $hashKey = array_merge(range('a', 'z'),range(0 ,9));
    $hash = array();

    while (count($hash) < 12) {
        $hash[] = $hashKey[array_rand($hashKey, 1)];
    }

    return implode('', $hash);
}

$hashes = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $hash = gen();

    while (in_array($hash, $hashes) === true) {
        var_dump($i . ' repeated');
        $hash = gen();
    }

    $hashes[] = $hash;
}
var_dump($hashes);
var_dump(count($hashes));
var_dump(count(array_unique($hashes))); here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com with no problem. 1770 ???

Comment: looks like array_rand is not truly random. it repeats.

Comment: @PeterDarmis You can finish it?

Comment: I got it, it can be done in Linux, but failed in Windows... if I use `srand()` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i mentioned in the comment the problem here is random sequence generated by array_rand is not truly random. after a large number of calls to array_rand function it tends to repeat. one possible solution is to seed the random number generator.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
$hash = gen();

while (in_array($hash, $hashes) === true) {
    var_dump($i . ' repeated');
    $hash = gen();

    //whenever a duplicate happen seed the generator  
    srand(microtime() * 10000000);
}

$hashes[] = $hash;
```

}